# Generate a sequence based on the given start?

Tags: excel, vba

An analyst observed that the upward movement of stocks on Bovespa is repeated according to a mathematical sequence. He wants to find out what the next bullish sequences will be. Generate and save in Excel cells using macro the sequence 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, ... up to its twentieth term?

```vb
Sub GerarSequencia()
    Dim num As Long 
    Dim previous As Long 
    Dim i As Integer 

    num = 0
    previous = 0
    
    For i = 1 To 20
        
        If i = 1 Then
            num = 1
        Else
            num = num + previous
        End If
        
        Cells(i, 1).Value = num
        
        previous = num
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried to generate the sequence of the exercise but did it generate another one?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow from another coder ;) Did you know that when you hit F8 while writing in de VBA IDE, you can follow the code rule by rule? You could see than that you only filled one number instead of two (which is necessary to create the sequence). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is a sommation of the earlier two values. So 1 + 3 = 4 and so on. Before you can start the sqequence you have to have two numbers. I think you can work with:

```
Sub GerarSequencia()
Dim intFirstNum, intSecondNum As Integer
Dim intCounter As Integer

intFirstNum = 1
intSecondNum = 3

Cells(1, 1) = intFirstNum
Cells(2, 1) = intSecondNum

For intCounter = 3 To 20

    Cells(intCounter, 1).Value = Cells(intCounter - 2, 1).Value + Cells(intCounter - 1, 1).Value

Next intCounter
    
End Sub
```

So you see that I have made two additional variables which are filled with 1 and 3 (if you change them you can start wherever you want). From that point on, I start the loop from position 3. This is because the first two are already known.

From that point on you can run the sequence. You don't need an if statement in that case.

Answer (score 0):

### Generating the Fibonacci Sequence

```vb
Sub GerarSequencia()
    
    Const nCOUNT As Long = 20
    
    Dim nPrev As Long: nPrev = -1 ' i = -1
    Dim nCurr As Long: nCurr = 2 ' i = 0
    
    Dim nNext As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To nCOUNT
        nNext = nPrev + nCurr ' sum up
        Cells(i, 1).Value = nNext ' write
        nPrev = nCurr ' swap
        nCurr = nNext ' swap
    Next i

'    ' Return the worksheet results in the Immediate window (Ctrl + G).
'    For i = 1 To nCOUNT
'        Debug.Print i, Cells(i, 1).Value
'    Next i
    
'    ' Return the worksheet results delimited by a comma
'    ' in the Immediate window (Ctrl + G).
'    Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(Cells(1, 1) _
'        .Resize(nCOUNT).Value), ",")
    
End Sub

' Join Result:
' 1,3,4,7,11,18,29,47,76,123,199,322,521,843,1364,2207,3571,5778,9349,15127
```